# Pass functions with unspecified parameters in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

So I've got a function like this:

```
template <typename T>
bool and_map(vector<T> v, function<bool(T)> fn) { ... }
```

And I want to pass it a vector and a lambda function like this:

```
[](int cell){ return(cell != -1); }
```

But I get an error which says there is no instance of and_map which takes these parameters.

When I do this it works:

```
template <typename T>
bool and_map(vector<T> v, function<bool(int)> fn) { ... }
```

How can I get it to work without specifying the parameter type of the passed function?

Comment: Lambdas are not `std::function`s.

Comment: make the second parameter a non-deducible context for `T` like `bool and_map(std::vector<T> v, typename identity<std::function<bool(T)>>::type fn) { }`

Comment: @Piotrs. I was just writing up a comment proposing the same solution when yours appeared. I think this is it. I'll leave it to you to post an answer.

Comment: Oh, you're right, I forgot that while I was writing the comment ;-). And you are right, this (simple and common) solution is not mentioned there, which is unfortunate.

Comment: just as a side note, `std::vector<T>` is actually `std::vector<T, A>`, don't forget about allocator's type when declaring a template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the correct way to accept a functor:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
bool and_map(vector<T> v, F fn) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

Having a function declared as:

```
template <typename T>
bool and_map(std::vector<T> v, std::function<bool(T)> fn)
```

a compiler tries to deduce a template type parameter `T` based on both arguments. However, a lambda expression *is not* `std::function<T>`, hence the compiler raises an error. To workaround that one can make the context of a second parameter (with `std::function<bool(T)>`) non-deducible with an *identity* trick:

```
template <typename T> struct identity { using type = T; };

template <typename T>
bool and_map(std::vector<T> v, typename identity<std::function<bool(T)>>::type fn)
{
    return {};
}

std::vector<int> v;
and_map(v, [](int cell){ return(cell != -1); });
```

so that type `T` will be deduced only based on the first argument, and then used to define the type of the second parameter.

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9dc02700c84d0689)

Comment: Non-deducible template parameters? That's my lesson for the day. Where can I get more information on that?

Comment: @RSahu *Non-deduced contexts* section at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction

Comment: This is still paying the type erasure costs that probably could have been avoided.